# Comparing two large datasets using a MapReduce programming model

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

Let's say I have two fairly large data sets - the first is called "Base" and it contains 200 million tab delimited rows and the second is call "MatchSet" which has 10 million tab delimited rows of similar data.

Let's say I then also have an arbitrary function called Match(row1, row2) and Match() essentially contains some heuristics for looking at row1 (from MatchSet) and comparing it to row2 (from Base) and determining if they are similar in some way.

Let's say the rules implemented in Match() are custom and complex rules, aka not a simple string match, involving some proprietary methods. Let's say for now Match(row1,row2) is written in psuedo-code so implementation in another language is not a problem (though it's in C++ today).

In a linear model, aka program running on one giant processor - we would read each line from MatchSet and each line from Base and compare one to the other using Match() and write out our match stats. For example we might capture: X records from MatchSet are strong matches, Y records from MatchSet are weak matches, Z records from MatchSet do not match. We would also write the strong/weak/non values to separate files for inspection.  Aka, a nested loop of sorts:

```
for each row1 in MatchSet
{
    for each row2 in Base
    {
        var type = Match(row1,row2);
        switch(type)
        {
            //do something based on type
        }
    }
}
```

I've started considering Hadoop streaming as a method for running these comparisons as a batch job in a short amount of time. However, I'm having a bit of a hardtime getting my head around the map-reduce paradigm for this type of problem.

I understand pretty clearly at this point how to take a single input from hadoop, crunch the data using a mapping function and then emit the results to reduce. However, the "nested-loop" approach of comparing two sets of records is messing with me a bit.

The closest I'm coming to a solution is that I would basically still have to do a 10 million record compare in parallel across the 200 million records so 200 million/n nodes * 10 million iterations per node. Is that that most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I down voted the question. In first instance it cannot be too heuristic, as we still look at 1 record per time (at least in the above description). Then the problem seems more to understand the map-reduce process then to call for an algorithm. Then the heuristic part is actually an algorithm which is not described here. So probably the question should be rewritten.

Comment: yea fair enough it was 5 years ago and that's probably true. I don't have an edit (as I don't actually care any more) and i can't seem to delete.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems to me that your problem can be arbitrarily complex and could be a victim of the [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Imagine for example that your rows represent n-dimensional vectors, and that your matching function is "strong", "weak" or "no match" based on the Euclidean distance between a Base vector and a MatchSet vector.  There are great techniques to solve these problems with a trade-off between speed, memory and the quality of the approximate answers.  Critically, these techniques typically come with known bounds on time and space, and the probability to find a point within some distance around a given MatchSet prototype, all depending on some parameters of the algorithm.

Rather than for me to ramble about it here, please consider reading the following:

1. [Locality Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)
2. The first few hits on Google Scholar when you search for "**locality sensitive hashing map reduce**".  In particular, I remember reading [Das, Abhinandan S., et al. "Google news personalization: scalable online collaborative filtering." Proceedings of the 16th international conference on World Wide Web. ACM, 2007] with interest.

Now, on the other hand if you can devise a scheme that is directly amenable to some form of hashing, then you can easily produce a key for each record with such a hash (or even a small number of possible hash keys, one of which would match the query "Base" data), and the problem becomes a simple large(-ish) scale join.  (I say "largish" because joining 200M rows with 10M rows is quite a small if the problem is indeed a join).  As an example, consider the way CDDB computes the 32-bit ID for any music CD [CDDB1 calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDDB#Example_calculation_of_a_CDDB1_.28FreeDB.29_disc_ID). Sometimes, a given title may yield slightly different IDs (i.e. different CDs of the same title, or even the same CD read several times).  But by and large there is a small set of distinct IDs for that title.  At the cost of a small replication of the MatchSet, in that case you can get very fast search results.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Section 3.5 - Relational Joins` in the paper '[Data-Intensive Text Processing
with MapReduce](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/MapReduce-book-final.pdf)'. I haven't gone in detail, but it might help you.

Comment: This is an interesting paper - but the joining here is all predicated on some shared key. If you consider my question, I don't have that luxury.

Comment: It's in my to-read list. But, I thought you would find it interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but your proposed solution is correct assuming that your single stream job does 200M * 10M Match() computations.  By doing N batches of (200M / N) * 10M computations, you've achieved a factor of N speedup.  By doing the computations in the map phase and then thresholding and steering the results to Strong/Weak/No Match reducers, you can gather the results for output to separate files.

If additional optimizations could be utilized, they'd like apply to both the single stream and parallel versions.  Examples include blocking so that you need to do fewer than 200M * 10M computations or precomputing constant portions of the algorithm for the 10M match set.